# Does spark ensure datalocality?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When I submit my spark job into `yarn cluster` with `--num-executers=4` , I can see in the spark UI, 4 executors are allocated in 4 nodes in the cluster. In my spark application I am taking inputs from various HDFS locations in various steps. But the allocated executors remain the same through out the execution.

My doubt is whether spark do anything for **data-locality**, since the nodes it selects at the very beginning irrespective of where input data situated(at least just in case of HDFS)?

I know map reduce does it in some extent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. Spark still uses Hadoop InputFormat and RecordReader interfaces and appropriate implementations like i.e. TextInputFormat. So Spark's behaviour in this case is very similar to common MapReduce. Spark driver retrieves block locations of the file and assigns task to executors with regard to data locality.

Comment: In map reduce, after computing the splits only mapper slots are decided based on locality checking. But in spark the executors are allocated statically in the beginning, then after whatever hdfs read happens they are done within in the previously allocated executers- not based on data locality check

Comment: Yep. But driver decides how to assign tasks to executors. So executors are allocated in a static way but driver decides which executor will process the given file block. I.e. you have a node 1 which stores block A of the file and executor E1 is running there, node 2 - block B, executor E2, 3 - C, E3. Spark driver will assign the processing of block A to executor E1, B - to E2, C to E3, but not i.e. block B to E3. Of course it does this only if possible. If the block is located on node 4 where is no running executors, the data will be transferred via network.